# What should be the lifecycle of afMongo's MongoClient?

Tags: mongodb, fantom, afbedsheet

Based on the [afMongo example](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afMongo/) I'm currently doing this:

```
mongoClient := MongoClient(ActorPool(), `mongodb://localhost:27017`)
collection  := mongoClient.db("mydb").collection("mycollection")
...
// inserts or queries here
...
mongoClient.shutdown
```

My understanding is that MongoClient uses a pooled connection. If that's correct then I believe I can share the MongoClient across all my DAOs and only shutting it down when the [afBedSheet](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afBedSheet/) application is shut down.

1. Is this assumption correct?
2. How can I hook the MongoClient shutdown to the afBedSheet shutdown, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. You only need one `MongoClient`.
2. Use the [RegistryShutdown](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afIoc/RegistryShutdown.html) service. When BedSheet shutsdown, it also shutsdowns the IoC registry.

I would have the `ConnectionManager` as a service, and shut that down. So in your `AppModule`:

```java
@Build
static ConnectionManager buildConnectionManager() {
    ConnectionManagerPooled(ActorPool(), `mongodb://localhost:27017`)
}

@Contribute { serviceType=RegistryShutdown# }
static Void contributeRegistryShutdown(Configuration config, ConnectionManager conMgr) {
    config.add(|->| { conMgr.shutdown } )
}
```

`MongoClient` could also be a service.

You could also rewrite the above to be a little more, um,  *correct*. I tend to use the `ActorPools` service to keep tabs on them.

```java
static Void bind(ServiceBinder binder) {
    binder.bind(MongoClient#)
}

@Build { serviceId="afMongo::ConnectionManager" }
static ConnectionManager buildConnectionManager(ConfigSource configSrc, ActorPools actorPools) {
    actorPool := actorPools.get("myPod.connectionManager")
    return ConnectionManagerPooled(actorPool , `mongodb://localhost:27017`)
}

@Contribute { serviceType=ActorPools# }
static Void contributeActorPools(Configuration config) {
    config["myPod.connectionManager"] = ActorPool() { it.name = "myPod.connectionManager"; it.maxThreads = 1 }
}

@Contribute { serviceType=RegistryShutdown# }
static Void contributeRegistryShutdown(Configuration config, ConnectionManager conMgr) {
    config["myPod.closeConnections"] = |->| {
        conMgr.shutdown
    }
}
```

`myPod.closeConnections` is just an arbitrary name and in the example it is not used anywhere else.`

But you *could* use it to override or remove the contribution. Some future test scenario could add a `MyTestAppModule` with the following:

```java
@Contribute { serviceType=RegistryShutdown# }
static Void contributeRegistryShutdown(Configuration config) {
    config.remove("myPod.closeConnections")
}
```

Probably not useful in this particular instance, but useful to know about.

Comment: I don't quite get it yet, sorry. Are "myPod.connectionManager" and "myPod.closeConnections" arbitrary names? where else are they used? And BTW, how to shutdown an afBedSheet application nicely? (not using Ctrl+C)

Comment: `myPod.connectionManager` is an arbitrary name given to the `ActorPool`.

Comment: Send a kill signal to the process to shutdown Wisp (+BedSheet) nicely.